# Backup & Restore desktop icons on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, remote-desktop, icons, desktop

My home computer, laptop and work PC have different desktop sizes.
When I remotely connect from home to work or laptop to work via Citrix, Citrix rearranges my desktop icons on my work PC.

I would like to backup my desktop icon layout so that after a remote session, I can restore them.

How do I backup the desktop icons (and their positions) on Windows 7?

Info:
Home PC:  Windows 10.
Laptop:   Windows 7.

Comment: Your remote connection simply *rearranges* your icons, but does not delete them, correct? If so, would simply restoring the location of the Desktop icons suffice?

Comment: Yes, restoring the positions would suffice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question accordingly. Requiring that the icons be backed up is likely to artificially limit possible answers that would otherwise be helpful to you.